# How to execute long job and then update widget from widget onclick method?

Tags: android, android-intent, widget, android-asynctask

I'm logging to bank account and getting account balance.
I calling this function from onUpdate in widget and running in AsyncTask

```
package com.example.oobe.widget.widgetexample;
public class ExampleAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider 
{
    (...)

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[]  appWidgetIds) 
    {
        (...)
        if (notFromAsyncTask)
            new MyAsyncTask().execute(context);
        (...)
    }
    (...)
}
```

In method onPostExecute I want to call onUpdate widget and putExtra strings.
How can I do this?

```
package com.example.oobe.widget.widgetexample;
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, BGZ> 
{
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected BGZ doInBackground(Object... params) 
    {
        this.context = (Context)params[0];
        return GetSomething();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(BGZ page)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleAppWidgetProvider.class);
        intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
        intent.putExtra("result", result);
        intent.putExtra("webpage", webPage);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
    (...)
}
```

If I doing like above I'm getting error:
.. Unable to find explicit activity class..

Can I do this from AsyncTask?
Can I call widget_update (onUpdate) with params to recognize that is from my AsyncTask?
Please give me little sample code (what to add to manifest if it must be broadcastreceiver and so on).

I have updated widget in onPostExecute but I think better method is to do that in ExampleAppWidgetProvider class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting this error

> Unable to find explicit activity class..

It may be due to this line

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ExampleAppWidgetProvider.class);
```

make sure ExampleAppWidgetProvider.class exist and

```
Context context = Activity.this;
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, ExampleAppWidgetProvider.class);
```

**UPDATE**

```
public class ExampleAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider 
{

   //your code .......
//asynctask as an inner class
   public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, BGZ> 
{
  doInBackground(){}
onPreExecute(){}
onPostExecute(){

//save result 
// or call your methods you need to run after your async call
}
}

}
```

Comment: `Context context = MyAsyncTask.this;` 
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from MyAsyncTask to Context` I was using context from ExampleAppWidgetProvider.
`public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, BGZ> 
{
 Context context;
 
 @Override
 protected BGZ doInBackground(Object... params) 
 {
  this.context = (Context)params[0];
  return GetSomething();
 }`

Comment: I updated the answer, I meant the activity whose context you require.

Comment: I've also updated my question (added some source) because I think i have everything that you are saying.

Comment: Async task is a background thread which you are calling from ExampleAppWidgetProvider and from that thread you are again calling ExampleAppWidgetProvider ,may be  this is causing the error. Instead save the result in postExecute and use it in ExampleAppWidgetProvider

Comment: How can I do this? Add event like AsyncTask.Done?

Comment: `MyAsyncTask at = new MyAsyncTask();
at.execute(context);
BGZ myresult = at.bgz;`

Comment: So it must be inner class and I must run task and get result like this: `MyAsyncTask at = new MyAsyncTask(); at.execute(context); BGZ myresult = at.bgz;` ?